# Is it correct to say "through bus" in the context "direct bus from one place to another"

Tags: phrase-usage

I live 12km away of my work. I don't have a car. I commute to my work by bus. But there is no one direct bus from my home to the work place. I need to take one bus, go to a station, get out and take another one.

Is it correct to say that there is `no through bus` instead of `no direct bus` to my work in the context above?

Is it usual for native speakers?

Comment: People would probably understand what you meant, but "direct" is the usual term.

Comment: You'd say "direct bus" or "one bus," like you might say, "There's no direct bus to my work. I have one transfer." In bus terminology, "a transfer" refers to getting off one bus and getting on another during one's journey to one's destination. When I lived in Chicago, there was no direct bus to my university from where I lived, so I had two transfers, meaning I had to take three buses to get there.

Comment: You might also say "non-stop".

Comment: [CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/through): << **through** [adjective] (DIRECT)
 
C1 [ only before noun ]
A through train or bus goes all the way from one place to another place without the passenger having to change trains or buses. >> General reference. Though I'd say 'through train' is a far stronger collocation than 'through bus', at least in the UK. [Google 2-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through+train%2Cthrough+bus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3).

Comment: Sometimes a bus that doesn’t stop at every single stop along the way is called an “***express*** bus”.

Comment: @Cascabel A bus (or train) journey that does not include a transfer isn't necessarily "non-stop" or even quicker. I once took a train from Doncaster to Reading and chose the 'direct' train so that I didn't have to change and it was cheaper. I found that it started in Newcastle Upon Tyne, ended in Weymouth and went through Doncaster, Birmingham. Didcot and Reading following a line on a map of England like the Mark of Zorro. It also stopped at just about every little station on the way. It took ages.

Comment: @BoldBen Interesting...In the USA, Greyhound calls it "non-stop". See "In 2010, Greyhound Express, a low-cost and few-stops or even **non-stop bus service**, was officially introduced to the Northeast of the United States, in order to allow for faster bus travels" As Jim points out, "express" is often used.  When I was younger and stupider, I once did the "direct" bus to New York from Arizona...it included many stops. Possibly  am mis-remembering it...

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, yes, I saw that definition of through on CD. But I didn't manage to find any other examples of 'through bus' in the internet. Once I said through bus to my colleague in a context and he seemed pondered about it. He is not native English speaker but has at least 20 years experience. Could you clarify what you mean by 'stronger collocation'?

Comment: In Britain we are likely to refer to a *change* rather than a *transfer*. When I go to Glasgow  by bus I have to *change*.

Comment: @Anton That's true, it's  long time since I used long distance public transport so I'd forgotten how to talk about that.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a *through bus* is similar to that of

> through train, noun
>
> Definition of through train
> : a train usually making a limited number of stops on which passengers may travel to a scheduled destination without changing to another train
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/through%20train)

It is used as such in Britain although we would also understand the notion of a direct bus. It is implicit, for example, in

> Travelling to the airport by bus couldn’t be easier, with direct links to Edinburgh city
>
> [Edinburgh Airport](https://www.edinburghairport.com/transport-links/buses-and-coaches)

Comment: Does the usage 'a through train' licence 'a through plane', 'a through steamer'? OP doesn't ask about trains.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the parallel and the commonplace nature of the two modes of transport seems to licence the usage. Planes and steamers are of a different nature and are less commonplace. I therefore feel that it is a reasonable and justifiable usage of through.